# What are some conditions that would cause severe exercise intolerance?

Tags: exercise, physical-health

I'm making a character and trying to be biologically accurate. Said character has transfusion-dependent anemia (from Gunther disease/congenital erythropoietic porphyria) so I suppose exercising would be hard by default, but what are some other conditions that would make physical training unhealthy? Ideally, I'm trying to make it so even light exercising is bad, but severe would cause vomiting/fainting/etc.

I posted this question on biology, but someone suggested I try asking here instead. I think that the question is less relevant there, so might as well ask here since I didn't get an answer anyway. I apologize for asking the same question twice.

Comment: There are literally dozens of possibilities and the big ones like heart failure should be easy to find with google. The person who referred you here should have mentioned that we expect you to do some homework on your own first.

Comment: I did, but that's exactly why it was hard for me to find a clear answer. There were many conditions so it was pretty overwhelming. I just needed some help to narrow everything down to the symptoms I mentioned, since despite there being many possibilities I kept finding conditions that would just make exercising hard, not outright harmful. I also considered heart failure, but apparently exercising is actually a good thing for people with that condition. I just thought that cep would have an impact or something, or that I needed a combination of conditions to get the result I want.

Comment: Heart failure comes in degrees and someone in class 4 isn't going to be doing any exercising. Almost any disease/condition will benefit from some degree of exercise, so if you exclude that then you're excluding almost everything. You really need a condition that makes any level of exercise actually harmful? (And not just temporarily, like after surgery or such.)

Comment: Well maybe not any level, but one where someone could never get even slightly fit no matter how hard they committed. But I'm trying to find something that would cause nausea/vomiting even with light training... maybe anemia would also make things worse, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the scenario? Is someone making an exercise and experiences symptoms, or someone is not making an exercise to avoid symptoms? What does the effect of symptoms need to be: just stopping the exercise, not being able to perform a planned task, experiencing pain or having a permanent damage caused by exercise? Also can you give some hint of a broader context?

Comment: Basically, the character avoided exercising throughout their entire childhood to avoid symptoms, and their effects are both experiencing pain (nausea, vomiting and exhaustion, fainting if gone too far) as well as stopping the exercise. Then as an adult there is a reason they want to get physically stronger, but can't due to everything mentioned.

Comment: Would you check for "mitral valve prolapse" and "cystic fibrosis?" If it suits to you, I can comment further if needed.

Comment: You know this could be a genetic disease. (Medical genetics). Who knows?  Get a full workup for this character.  Off the bat the character could try some coq10 and melatonin (melatonin for  mitochondria). Under a physicians supervision.  Could be some mitochondrial issue.

Comment: Entire childhood?  Here is doctor John Shoffner. This happens to be on a possible subset of potential mitochondrial issues. I do not believe John is in active practice now. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eSqZKVtlKNs  Anyway put it on your list maybe.

Comment: You can look into B1 Thiamine also for your character.   There can be some odd issues with this as well.  There can be GI issues with thiamine too.  Heart issues etc. But it may not be as simple as taking B1 off the shelf. All this needs to be supervised by a doctor too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a disease with childhood onset that requires exercise restriction, Long QT Syndrome (LQTS) may work, specifically LQT1. [Here](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health-topics/long-qt-syndrome) is a lay overview. For more detail, see [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6785594/). I'm not a cardiologist, and have never seen a patient with LQTS, so I'm honestly not sure how variable the presentation is. Generally, for LQT1, exercise or stress induced tachycardia can cause a life threatening arrhythmia called [torsades de pointes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsades_de_pointes) and sudden death.

Treatment of LQT1 includes avoidance of stress, exercise restriction, and beta blockers. As discussed in the linked review above, certain extreme phenotypes may not be fully controlled with beta blockers. Pain, nausea, or perceived exercise intolerance (e.g., fatigue), the symptoms you mentioned in your comment, are not part of the described symptom  complex. Rather elevated heart rate leads to the malignant arrhythmia. The symptom complex is that of the arrhythmia (palpitations, fainting, seizures, and death).

Answer (score 2):

Here are medical conditions that come to mind, each with different symptoms:

1. Severe exercise-induced asthma. Symptoms will be severe wheezing, O2 drop, potentially even death. Long-term anti-inflammatory medications can prevent exacerbations, though exacerbations can still be triggered in specific situations. Imagine a *deconditioned* character, in *fight-and-flight*, *running from danger* in *cold weather*, and especially with bronchi inflamed from *a respiratory infection*.
2. POTS - postural orthostatic hypotension.  A type of dysautonomia, a likely autoimmune condition that can trigger O2 drops, brain fog, nausea, fainting from minor exercise, or (in very severe cases) even from standing up and staying upright.  It used to be thought that graduated exercise would help everyone. Not true.
3. Chronic fatigue syndrome. Often infection-triggered, likely autoimmune, with antibodies to adrenergic receptors (adrenergic - think adrenalin). Causes *post-exercise malaise*, meaning dysproportionately severe symptoms for days/weeks after overdoing things, including much increased odds of fainting from POTS, overwhelming fatigue, GI symptoms (nausea, inability to digest..).  Depending on the patient, the "overdoing" may be physical or cognitive, ranging from doing a college entrance exam, to cooking for a family visit, to walking around the block.

Comment: Systemic Exertion Intolerance Disease (SEID) has been proposed as an alternative name for chronic fatigue syndrome, see CDC website and 2015 Institute of Medicine report called Beyond Myalgic Encephalomyelitis/Chronic Fatigue Syndrome: Redefining an Illness.